# Improper mutiple integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I would like to solve the following integral:

```
Integrate[y Erf[a Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]
            Exp[-b ((x - c)^2 + y^2)], {x, -∞, ∞}, 
         {y, 0, ∞}, Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}]
```

If I add such input in Mathematica, it takes ages to solve it and in the end it could not. The solution is obviously a function of a, b, and c. Any ideas, tricks how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way...

*Convert to polar coordinates*

```
Integrate[
 r (r Sin[t]) Erf[a r]/r Exp[-b ((r Cos[t] - c)^2 + (r Sin[t])^2)],
 {r, 0, Infinity}, {t, 0, Pi}, Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}]
```

But that doesn't work, so...

*Do the `t` integral first*

```
tInt = Integrate[r r Sin[t] Erf[a r]/r Exp[-b ((r Cos[t] - c)^2 + (r Sin[t])^2)],
 {t, 0, Pi}]
(*
  (E^(-b (c + r)^2) (-1 + E^(4 b c r)) Erf[a r])/(2 b c)
*)
```

The `r` integral won't evaluate still, so...

*Try differentiating with respect to the parameter `a`*

This trick I learned in Salomon Bochner's *Fourier Integrals*.  In this case, I should note that `tInt` equals zero at `a -> 0`.  The value of `daInt` is the partial derivative with respect to `a` of the integral we wish to find.  Later we will antidifferentiate with respect to `a` (using a substitution).  Normally, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, I would subtract the value at `a == 0`, but since the value is zero, you won't see that step below.

```
daInt = Integrate[D[tInt, a], {r, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}]
(*
   E^(-((a^2 b c^2)/(a^2 + b)))/(a^2 + b)^(3/2)
*)
```

But this won't integrate with respect to `a`, so...

*Try another substitution, `u = a^2 + b`*

The Jacobian factor is `1/(2 Sqrt[u - b])`.

```
aInt = Integrate[1/(2 Sqrt[u - b]) daInt /. a^2 -> u - b,
          u, Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}];
Simplify[aInt /. u -> a^2 + b, a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0]
(* (Sqrt[π] Erf[a Sqrt[b/(a^2 + b)] c])/(2 b^(3/2) c) *)
```

To me, getting an answer at this step was a miracle....so

*Check numerically*

```
With[{a = 2, b = 1, c = 1},
 {NIntegrate[
   y Erf[a Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] / Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] Exp[-b ((x - c)^2 + y^2)],
   {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, 0, ∞}],
  (Sqrt[π] Erf[a Sqrt[b/(a^2 + b)] c])/(2 b^(3/2) c) // N}
 ]
(* {0.70375, 0.70375} *)
```

You can verify for other values as well.  Seems like I didn't make a mistake. So the answer is
$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\ \text{erf}\left(a c
   \sqrt{\frac{b}{a^2+b}}\right)}{2 b^{3/2} c}$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I will go trough all the steps!

Comment: @user113891 You're welcome! I added some explanation of some steps.

Comment: You're the real `baba ji` :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I have tried now to solve the similar integral following your steps. Now the integral is

Comment: @MichaelE2 I have tried now to solve the similar integral following your steps. The only difference is that the erf and exp functions in the original integral are multiplied by x, instead of y. After the conversion to Polar Coordinates, I would get:
    tInt = Integrate[r r Cos[t] Erf[a r]/r Exp[-b ((r Cos[t] - c)^2 + (r Sin[t])^2)],
 {t, 0, Pi}]
(* E^(-b (c^2 + r^2)) \[Pi] r BesselI[1, 2 b c r] Erf[a r] *)
Now with BesselI function it is not possible anymore to do the last step integration. I tried to express cos[t] with sin[t] via trigonometric identities, but it didn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Actually, all the steps apart from the last one worked, and with Cos[t], the problem has reduced to finding this integral:
    Integrate[E^(-((a^2 b c^2)/(a^2 + b)))/(a^2 + b)^2,a]

Comment: @user113891 No ideas for the integral.  You can replace the exponential by its power series and integrate term by term.  I get an infinite series in terms of `Hypergeometric2F1`.  If you can do without a symbolic formula, `NIntegrate`, `NDSolve` and `ParametricNDSolve` might be useful.